# Show that a set is free

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $F(a,b)$ be the free group on $\{a,b\}$. Show that the set $\{a,b^2\}$ is free, yet cannot be extended to a basis.

How do I show that a set is free. I couldn't manage to do working with the definition of free groups.

Definition as given in class:
[image]

Comment: What is your definition of free set?

Comment: Anyway, if there were some relation on $a,b^2$, then this wuold give you a relation on $a,b$: but such a relation does not exist (it's the trivial relation!), so that $a,b^2$ have the trivial relation.

Comment: @Crostul , what do you mean by the trivial relation? We've just started to learn the subject and I'm a bit confused. What if instead of {a,b^2} it was {a,ab}?

Comment: If you don't give us the definition of free set, we cannot help you. I am using the following one: a set $ \{ a_i \}_i$ of a group $G$ is free whenever the unique group homomorphism $F(\{ X_i \}_i ) \to G$ defined by $X_i \mapsto a_i$ has trivial kernel. That kernel is indeed what is called "the set of relations on $ \{ a_i \}_i$", and the set is free exactly when the set of relations is trivial.

Comment: For example, $\{ a, a^2\}$ is not free, since $X_1^2X_2^{-1}$ is a nontrivial relation on that set.

Comment: OK, I have updated the question and added the definition.
On your last example why is it a nontrivial relation on that set? and where did the X^(-1) came from?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK: a relation is a nothing but a word representing the trivial element. Now, if you can find some reduced word with $a,b^2, a^{-1}, b^{-2}$ representing the trivial element, this is a word with $a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}$ (can you see it?). But $\{ a,b \}$ is free by definition, hence this reduced word is actually the empty word.

Comment: Thank you for your help and for your patience. I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

suppose we have a reduced word in $a$ and $b^2$ - $$w=a^{k_1}\cdot b^{2l_1}\cdots a^{k_r}.$$ which gives the trivial element. then we get a reduced word on $a, b$ that gives the trivial element, which is a contradiction. we can do the same for a word that ends with a power of $b^2$.

now, if we could complete $\{a,b^2\}$ to a basis of $\mathbb{F}_2$ then we would have $$a^{k_1}\cdot b^{2l_1}\cdots a^{k_r}=b$$ for some coefficients (the same is needed to be done for the case where the word ends with a power of $b^2$) so we have that $a^{k_1}\cdot b^{2l_1}\cdots a^{k_r}b^{-1}$ is the trivial element in $\{a,b\}$, which is again a contradiction